# SOCP Solver Error for fPortoflio using solveRsocp

Tags: r, solver, portfolio

I would like to use an R SOCP solver to get similar results to the following paper: http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2014/05/4366.pdf

And doing a bit of googling, it seems like it used to be part of `fPortfolioSolver`, but that package looks like it no longer exists....

And this looks like how it used to be implemented...

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2010q2/006074.html

The solver still sort of exists here:

https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/fPortfolio/R/solveRsocp.R?view=markup&root=rmetrics&pathrev=3507

But it should be referencing the `Rsocp` package available here:

https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=156

However there are a few errors that need to help it to get it to work

e.g. line 117 needs to change to

```
Rsocp:::.SqrtMatrix
```

and line 165 needs to change to

```
optim <- Rsocp::socp(f, A, b, C, d, N, x, z, w, control)
```

but when running the following code, I get the following error...

```
lppData=100*LPP2005.RET[,1:6] 
maxRetSpec=portfolioSpec() 
setTargetRisk(maxRetSpec)=0.07 
setSolver(maxRetSpec)="solveRsocp"
efficientPortfolio(data=lppData, spec=maxRetSpec, constraints="LongOnly") 

 Error in .socp.phase1(f, A, b, N, control) : Phase 1 failed, alpha>=0 

traceback()
6 stop("Phase 1 failed, alpha>=0") 
5 .socp.phase1(f, A, b, N, control) 
4 Rsocp::socp(f, A, b, C, d, N, x, z, w, control) at solveRsocp.R#165
3 .rsocp(f = args$f, A = args$A, b = args$b, C = args$C, d = args$d, 
N = args$N, targetRisk = args$targetRisk, mu = args$mu, Scale = args$Scale) at    solveRsocp.R#64
2 Solver(data, spec, constraints) 
1 efficientPortfolio(data = lppData, spec = maxRetSpec, constraints = "LongOnly")
```

Any help to solve this situation so that the solver works and that the paper could be replicated would be greatly be appreciated...

Comment: I'm stuck with this same problem. I'm trying to learn how to use solveRsocp, but, even after adjusting the target risk to 0.1, I still get an error. Another error though. `Error in eqsumW[2, -1] : subscript out of bounds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Fixed by changing

```
setTargetRisk(maxRetSpec)=0.07
```

to

```
setTargetRisk(maxRetSpec)=0.1
```