# Translating code that carries out SOCP/SDP optimisation from MATLAB to R

Tags: r, matlab, mathematical-optimization

I have the following MATLAB code which was used in the linked paper (http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2014/05/4366.pdf), and would like to be able to use the `Rsocp` package  to be able to carry out the same function but in R. The `Rsocp` package is available by using the command:

```
install.packages("Rsocp", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

and through the `socp()` function it carries out a similar function to `solvesdp(constraints, -wcvar, ops)` in the MATLAB code below.

I do not have MATLAB which makes this problem more difficult for me to solve.

The issue I have is the R's `socp()` function takes matrices as inputs that reflect the data(/covariance matrix and average return values) and constraints all together, where as the MATLAB code seems to be optimising a function...in this specific case it looks like its optimising `-wcvar` to get the optimal weights, so I am unsure of how to set up my problem in R to get similar results.

The MATLAB code I would therefore like help in translating to R is as follows:

```
function [w] = rgop(T, mu, sigma, epsilon)

% This function determines the robust growth-optimal portfolio
%   Input parameters:
%       T       - the number of time periods
%       mu      - the mean vector of asset returns
%       sigma   - the covariance matrix of asset returns
%       epsilon - violation probability
%   Output parameters:
%       w       - robust growth-optimal portfolios

% the number of assets
n = length(mu);

% portfolio weights 
w = sdpvar(n,1);

% mean and standard deviation of portfolio
rp = w'*mu;
sigmap = sqrt(w'*sigma*w);

% preclude short selling
constraints = [w >= 0];  %#ok<NBRAK>

% budget constraint
constraints = [constraints, sum(w) == 1];

% worst-case value-at-risk (theorem 4.1)
wcvar = 1/2*(1 - (1 - rp + sqrt((1-epsilon)/epsilon/T)*sigmap)^2 - ((T-1)/epsilon/T)*sigmap^2);

 % maximise WCVAR 
ops = sdpsettings('solver','sdpt3','verbose',0);
solvesdp(constraints, -wcvar, ops);

 w = double(w);

 end
```

For the square root function of the covariance matrix one can use:

```
 Rsocp:::.SqrtMatrix()
```

Note this question is partially related to my previous question however is more focused on getting the worst case VaR weights:

[SOCP Solver Error for fPortoflio using solveRsocp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509960/socp-solver-error-for-fportoflio-using-solversocp)

Perhaps a good start would be to use this code where the `Rsocp` package has already been used...

https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/fPortfolio/R/solveRsocp.R?view=markup&root=rmetrics&pathrev=3507

*EDIT*

I think the MATLAB code for the solvesdp function is available from this link:

https://code.google.com/p/vroster/source/browse/trunk/matlab/yalmip/solvesdp.m?r=11

Also a quick question about SOCP optimisations in general...would the result obtained via SOCP optimisation be the same as that achieved using other methods of optimisation? will the only difference be speed and efficiency?

*EDIT2*

Since it was requested...

```
rgop <- function(tp, mu, sigma, epsilon){
  # INPUTS
  # tp - the number of time periods
  # mu - the mean vector of asset returns
  # sigma - the covariance matrix of asset returns
  # epsilon - violation probability

  # OUTPUT
  # w - robust growth-optimal portfolios

  #n is number of assets
  n <- length(mu)

  # portfolio weights (BUT THIS IS THE OUTPUT)
  # for now will assume equal weight
  w <- rep(1/n,n)

  # mean and standard deviation of portfolio
  rp <- sum(w*mu)

  sigmap <- as.numeric(sqrt(t(w) %*% sigma %*% w))

  # worst-case value-at-risk (theorem 4.1)
  wcvar = 1/2*(1 - (1 - rp + sqrt((1-epsilon)/epsilon/tp)*sigmap)^2 - ((tp-1)/epsilon/tp)*sigmap^2);

  # optimise...not sure how to carry out this optimisation...
  # which is the main thrust of this question...
  # could use DEoptim...but would like to understand the SOCP method

}
```

Comment: The `socp` function in the `Rsocp` package requires a SOCP in standard form, and it looks like MATLAB's `solvesdp` has a good deal more leeway. You'll need to reformulate your optimization problem into standard form. Section 2 of [this document](http://retis.sssup.it/~bini/teaching/optim2010/cone_programming.pdf) has a number of reformulation tricks. If you can't figure it out, I would suggest asking a question on math.stackexchange.com, since your problem is really an exercise in mathematics at this point.

Comment: If you have the code that carries out `solvesdp` when the settings are set as `ops = sdpsettings('solver','sdpt3','verbose',0);` could that part of the MATLAB code be used to see how it deals with constraints?, such that an `r_solvesdp`  could be created too which mimics the ability to use the a similar setup?

Comment: Also a quick question about SOCP optimisations in general...would the result obtained via SOCP optimisation be the same as that achieved using other methods of optimisation? will the only difference be speed and efficiency?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Surely you don't run into problems at the first line `n = length(mu);`

Comment: The question now has a bit of R code...which shows some translation...but doesnt solve the main thrust of the question...

Answer (score 1):

SOCP is just a fast way of finding the minimum in cases where you know enough about the problem to constrain it in certain technical ways.  As you're discovering these constraints can be tricky to formulate, so it is worth asking if you need the speed. Often the answer is yes, but for debugging/exploration purposes brute numerical optimisation using R's optim function can be fruitful.

Comment: Thank you for that, but would you be able to help out on the translation of code to get a practical solution?

Comment: A practical solution is one that produces answers.  You want to understand constraints in convex optimisation?  You better read the famous book :)

http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/