# R - fPortfolio - Error in eqsumW[2, -1] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

Ran :

```
require(fPortfolio)
lppData=100*LPP2005.RET[,1:6]
maxRetSpec=portfolioSpec()
setTargetRisk(maxRetSpec)=0.3
setSolver(maxRetSpec)="solveRsocp"
efficientPortfolio(data=lppData, spec=maxRetSpec,constraints="LongOnly")
```

I get :

```
Error in eqsumW[2, -1] : subscript out of bounds
```

The message itself is pretty clear, however I don't know what is supposed to populate eqsumW[2, -1]

I have looked inside `solveRsocp`, managed to tweak it so that it wouldn't need `eqsumW[2, -1]`, replaced it by 1 because 0 didn't work (I get the same error message as [SOCP Solver Error for fPortoflio using solveRsocp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509960/socp-solver-error-for-fportoflio-using-solversocp) and the solution doesn't seem to help), I then get a result but the sum of weights is over 1.
I have also tried changing the solver to `Rdonlp2` but I get an equal-weighted portfolio that is not constrained.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a mistake in the code, at least I think it's a mistake.

`eqsumW[2, -1]` is supposed to refer to the Budget row in the Equal Matrix Constraints.

However, when you don't have a set target return, the budget row is actually the first one. Therefore you need to replace `eqsumW[2,-1]` and `eqsumW[2,1]` by `eqsumW[1,-1]` and `eqsumW[1,1]` in `.rsocpArguments`