# Configuring SOCP solver in 'R'

Tags: r, optimization, solver, portfolio, quantitative-finance

I am trying to use the **`Rsocp`** package in **`R`** to solve a linear optimization problem with quadratic constraints. Much like in [R - fPortfolio - Error in eqsumW[2, -1] : subscript out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358168/r-fportfolio-error-in-eqsumw2-1-subscript-out-of-bounds/34956444#34956444)

More specifically I am attempting to maximize an expected return given a target risk parameter and portfolio/position limits.

```
install.packages("Rsocp", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
install.packages("fPortfolio")
require(fPortfolio)
require(Rsocp)
```

I run

```
lppData=100*LPP2005.RET[,1:6] 
maxRetSpec=portfolioSpec() 
setTargetRisk(maxRetSpec)=0.07
groupConstraints <- c("minsumW[1:6]=-.75",
                    "maxsumW[1:6]=1.75")
boxConstraints <- c("minW[1:6]=-1",
                    "maxW[1:6]=1")
bgConstraints <- c(groupConstraints, boxConstraints)
setSolver(maxRetSpec)="solveRsocp"
efficientPortfolio(data=lppData, spec=maxRetSpec, constraints=bgConstraints)
```

and get the following error...

> `Error in eqsumW[2, -1] : subscript out of bounds`

It is my understand that Rsocp is a second order cone solver designed specifically for this purpose. Having gone through several different stackexchange forums it seems there are several people who have encountered this problem with unsatisfactory solutions. I was wondering if anyone has had success using the Rsocp solver that could give me a hand working through this error? Or alternatively can someone point me towards an 'R' solver that can handle this type of optimization problem?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example that anyone else can simply copy and paste into their session to run.  All library statements and inputs need to be included.  Cut down your data to the minimum needed to illustrate the problem.   See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Salute to Boston, @Fanderson. You might already know, that StackOverflow executes an **MCVE**-code policy for posting Questions. Would you consider adding and update with such a **M**-inimum **C**-omplete **V**-erifiable **E**-xample of code, which is run-able and which replicates the issue you are facing? That would be exactly what StackOverflow defined in the Community Nettiquette as a part of the desired professional Community habit. **Anyway, welcome&enjoy this great Community and become active, contributing member among of thic gang of knowledge supported by people all around the globe**

Comment: Sorry for not listing the above packages in the original, I think the above code should run, the dataset is part of the fPortfolio package.